# Unable to install windows 7 on Asus X553M

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios, acpi

I bought a new ASUS X553M laptop with DOS pre-installed, I am trying to install windows 7 but getting error "The BIOS in this system is not fully ACPI compliant. STOP : 0x000000A5"

Please help.

Comment: Is this helpufl? http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19430879 - 1) says to disconnect any hardware attached to the laptop. 2) update to the latest bios - 208 seems to be the latest for your laptop: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X553MA/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: i have updated bios but giving same problem

Answer (score 4):

I bought same laptop from Amazon.in & getting same issue but lucky resolved it as well. DO one thing go to BIOS by pressing F2 in BIOS there is am option of choosing windows by default its win 8.x just change it to win 7 then save changes & exit. Issue resolved install win 7 & enjoy.

Comment: By the way which graphic driver you installed do you have link?